# Create a dropshadow only layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, transparency, layer-style

I want to make a white rounded rectangle (which will be used for an in-game alpha mask) and another layer which contains a drop shadow.  That way I can do quick export for the two layers. **WITHOUT RASTERIZING**

I use blue and red to help me provide the contrast to help me debug.

[image]

I have a rounded rectangle which I converted to a path.

[image]

I've created a vector mask where I reversed

[image]

When I create the clipping mask I get the following.  Which is close to what I want except for the white background as I just wanted the drop shadow with a transparent background.

[image]

I think I can do a layer mask but it seems I have to rasterize the path.  This is basically what I got when I rasterize.

[image]

Comment: Hi Archimedes, welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Create a shape layer in the desired shape and with any colour fill;
2. Add your drop shadow using Layer Styles;
3. Make sure that on the Drop Shadow settings, the box 'Layer Knocks Out Drop Shadow' is ticked;
4. In the Layers palette, reduce the layer's 'Fill' property (*not* Opacity) to 0%.

'Fill' functions exactly the same as Opacity, except it doesn't affect any layer styles you applied.

Comment: how to knock the layer below making the transparent hole? I mean of course one could duplicate the shape with the shadow and make it a vector mask...

Comment: @Luciano Not sure I follow. Was that the question? *thinking*

Comment: it looks like. White layer with a hole and a drop shadow falling on the layer. Or maybe I'm over-reading

Comment: I think you are, the OP just marked this as the preferred answer. Thanks for thinking along, though! :)

Comment: I can paste my output in your answer if you are okay.

Comment: No, that's okay @ArchimedesTrajano. We are not a forum, and we are very precise about what is an answer and what is a question. If you want, you can show (and discuss) stuff in [chat] though!

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano better not add that to the answer; Vincent no worries, the question got me thinking in another direction, now I wonder if it's possible to do a one-layer solution...